# Errors translating Linq expression to URI: The method 'Select' is not supported

Tags: c#, .net, linq, wcf-data-services, odata

Here is my failing code

```
        var query = from gg in Client.wcf.context.Good
                    from cc in Client.wcf.context.Customer
                    from ch in Client.wcf.context.CashHeading
                    from cs in Client.wcf.context.Cash
                    where ch.Id_customer == cc.Id
                    where cs.Id_cashheading == ch.Id
                    where gg.Id == cs.Id_good
                    select new CustomerOrderResult {
                        CustomerID = cc.Id,
                        Price = gg.Price.HasValue ? gg.Price.Value : 0,
                        Date = ch.Date.HasValue ? ch.Date.Value : DateTime.Now
                    };
        List<CustomerOrderResult> qqq = query.ToList();
```

Additional information: The method 'Select' is not supported.

and this solves the error : [Why this Linq doesn't work (Error translating Linq expression to URI: Can only specify query options (orderby, where, take, skip)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577458/why-this-linq-doesnt-work-error-translating-linq-expression-to-uri-can-only-s)

query is another linq and in total it's WCF Data client to Server (Entity) application full source file is [Here, on GitHub](https://github.com/Nensha/ENT/blob/master/ENT_Client/MainForm.cs)

other linq queries there work fine

error : `+      query   {Error translating Linq expression to URI: The method 'Select' is not supported.}   System.Linq.IQueryable<CustomerOrderResult> {System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery<CustomerOrderResult>.DataServiceOrderedQu`ery}

Comment: From the stack trace/code it looks like date is null, but you could check with a debugger.  Is date a nullable?  If yes try using date.HasValue && date...

Comment: no, there is nothing nullable in query result

Comment: Are you sure that `c != null`?

Comment: yes, I edited code, inner exception appears early there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `query` contains `null`. Try

```
where x != null && x.CustomerID == c.Id
```