# Why this Linq doesn't work (Error translating Linq expression to URI: Can only specify query options (orderby, where, take, skip)

Tags: c#, linq, odata

```
var query = from ch in Client.wcf.context.CashHeading
    where ch.Id_customer == customern//cc.Id
    from cs in Client.wcf.context.Cash
    where cs.Id_cashheading == ch.Id
    from gg in Client.wcf.context.Good
    where gg.Id == cs.Id_good
    select gg.Price.Value;
```

I'm getting inner error processing it:

> Error translating Linq expression to URI:  Can only specify query
>   options (orderby, where, take, skip) after last navigation.

I can't understand why, full sources  [Here, on GitHub](https://github.com/Nensha/ENT/blob/master/ENT_Client/MainForm.cs)

Comment: I believe the error is saying that have to put the where clause after all 3 froms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you have to condense your where clause into a *single* where clause after *all* of the navigations (`from`) have been performed, like so:

```
var query = 
    from ch in Client.wcf.context.CashHeading
    from cs in Client.wcf.context.Cash
    from gg in Client.wcf.context.Good
    where 
        ch.Id_customer == customern && //cc.Id
        cs.Id_cashheading == ch.Id &&
        gg.Id == cs.Id_good
    select gg.Price.Value;
```

Granted, this doesn't *seem* optimal, as it would seem that it's going to do cross join all of the tables and *then* perform the filtering, but remember, you're probably dealing with [`IQueryable<T>` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx) implementations, meaning that this will more than likely be interpreted and then optimized by whatever handles the translated queries.